# Checking to brokerage transfer latency: Why does it take 3 days to move money, even at the same bank?

Tags: banking, bank-account, online-banking, brokerage

It takes my bank 3 days to transfer money back and forth to my brokerage account, even though my checking and brokerage accounts are both with the same bank.

I don't understand why in the digital age anything should take more than 30 seconds.

Is this a limitation of my specific bank, or is this regulated by the SEC or other body?

Comment: Banks don't have brokerages.  ***Holding companies*** have *both* banks *and* brokerages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some companies have banks and brokerages that are completely separate systems. So you could be actually running ACH transactions between two different banking entities.

Bank of America used to have significant latency between BoA accounts, because they ran into delays integrating Fleet, BankSouth and BoA systems.

Answer (score 6):

this time float is a fabulous money maker for the banks.  someone owns that money during that time and creams whatever interest is earned during those few days, and guess who that is.  I think most of is is deliberate

Answer (score 5):

It could be a delay because of the Automated Clearinghouse (ACH) process.

At least that's the explanation on [this thread](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Bank-accounts-and-credit-cards/Why-does-it-take-so-long-to-transfer-money-from-my-bank-account/m-p/51940) at the PayPal forums, and [on Prosper.com](http://www.prosper.com/help/).

Answer (score 1):

My bank (USAA) moves money to and from a USAA brokerage account instantly. They also have instant transfers from their money market funds to checking, savings, and brokerage.

It takes the 3 days to go to another institution, though.

Comment: To and from brokerage or just to?

Comment: Both ways. I'm talking about brokerage cash/money-market though, if you sell securities then I think it takes longer to get the proceeds of that. But just moving cash is instant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a limitation of your bank. Every bank I've ever used had instant transfers between accounts at the same bank.